# how to iterate throught an array of objects and concate the contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the object (obj1) that is posted below. As shown  in it, it contains an array of objects called "favoritePlayers".

what I am trying to do is, to create a function or add an array prototype so that I can iterate through each element in the array separately and get the following output:

"messi plays in barcelona"
"totti plays in roma"

I tried to solve it as shown below but what I get is

```
[ 'undefinedplays in[object Object]',
'undefinedplays in[object Object]' ]
```

**obj1**:

```
var obj1 = {
score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
avgScore: null,
favoritePlayers: [
    {
        name: "messi",
        club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
        name: "totti",
        club: "roma"
    }
],

calcAvgScore: function () {
    var sumOfScores = this.score.reduce(function (prev, cur, index, array)   
{

        return prev + cur;

    })

    return (sumOfScores / this.score.length);
},

myFavoritePlayersInfo: function () {
    console.log(this.favoritePlayers.join());
},

}
```

**my attempts:**
    //this code was added outside the scope of obj1

```
Array.prototype.concat1 = ( (array) => {
var tempArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

tempArray[i] = array.slice(i, i+1).name + "plays in" + array.slice(i,   
i+1);

}

return tempArray;

});
```

**update_1**

I added the following lines to obj1:

```
getPlaysIn:function() {
    this.favoritePlayers.forEach( (favoritePlayer)=> {
        return favoritePlayer.name + " plays in " + favoritePlayer.club;
```

and I call it as follows:

```
console.log(obj1.getPlaysIn());
```

but the results i get is

```
undefined
```

Comment: `obj1.favoritePlayers.map(player=>player.name+' plays in '+player.club)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the players, and create the array you want:

```js
var obj1 = {
  score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
  lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
  avgScore: null,
  favoritePlayers: [{
      name: "messi",
      club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
      name: "totti",
      club: "roma"
    }
  ],
  
  getPlaysIn() {
    return this.favoritePlayers.map(function(player) {
      return player.name + ' plays in ' + player.club;
    });
  }
};

console.log(obj1.getPlaysIn());
```

Comment: would you please have a look at the update_1 section I added above

Comment: @LetsamrIt - I've looked, and my answer already solves this because it uses Array#map instead of forEach. Run the snippet.

Comment: yes..it works with .map function..but would you please tell em why the same code doesnt work when .forEach is used?

Comment: Because Array#forEach is used for side effects, it changes something, but doesn't return anything, while map creates and returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the `favoritePlayers` array

```js
var obj1 = {
  score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
  lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
  avgScore: null,
  favoritePlayers: [{
      name: "messi",
      club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
      name: "totti",
      club: "roma"
    }
  ]
}
obj1.favoritePlayers.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.name + ' plays ' + item.club)
})
```

If you want to use prototype

```js
var obj1 = {
  score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
  lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
  avgScore: null,
  favoritePlayers: [{
      name: "messi",
      club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
      name: "totti",
      club: "roma"
    }
  ]
}
Array.prototype.customForEach = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    console.log(this[i].name + ' plays ' + this[i].club);

  }
}
obj1.favoritePlayers.customForEach();
```

Comment: @LetsamrIt You can... have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xLnbne98/1).

Comment: would you please have a look at the update_1 section I added above

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the object and return it the way you see fit.

```
let playerInfo = obj1.favoritePlayers.map(playerObj => {
   return playerObj["name"] + "plays for " + playerObj["club"];
});
```

Comment: Nothing to figure out... it's basics. `Object.prototype.<function name> = function(){}`

Comment: would you please have a look at the update_1 section I added above

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @LetsamrIt I have included it in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```js
var obj1 = {
score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
avgScore: null,
favoritePlayers: [
    {
        name: "messi",
        club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
        name: "totti",
        club: "roma"
    }
],
getPlaysIn:function() {
   var returnVal = "";
   this.favoritePlayers.forEach( (favoritePlayer)=> {
        returnVal += favoritePlayer.name + " plays in " + favoritePlayer.club+"\n";
        });
    return returnVal;
   }
}

console.log(obj1.getPlaysIn());
```

Comment: would you please have a look at the update_1 section I added above

Comment: When we use return inside forEach() we will break out of the loop not function. And in your code function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = {
  score: [10, 22, 30, 55, 70, 90],
  lettersOfMyName: ["a", "m", "r"],
  avgScore: null,
  favoritePlayers: [{
      name: "messi",
      club: "barcelona"
    },

    {
      name: "totti",
      club: "roma"
    }
  ]
}

var a = obj1.favoritePlayers;
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
console.log(a[i].name+ " " + "plays " +" "+ a[i].club)
};
```